# Existence of Missing Index in MySQL. Does it exist?

Tags: mysql

I have been working a bit with MySQL and SQL Server, and I have a question: if the `"Missing Index"` script exists in MySQL

In SQL Server I know that it shows the missing indices of each table in a database, and by that I would like to know if it exists in MySQL or something similar to this SQl Server script that can be executed.

Beforehand I would be very grateful.

Comment: To clarify, for those unfamiliar with SQL Server - SQL Server uses statistics, queries, and query plans to identify cases where an index that does not exist would have been useful. Based on the frequency with which these queries and plans are used, it develops a relative value for these "missing" indexes. The recommendations aren't always useful. but can provide food for thought and directions for investigation.

Comment: [_DIY cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another article here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626876/how-to-find-missing-indexes-in-mysql

I, too, would recommend using the explain plan and looking at results.  I have had instances where adding an index to a table actually slowed the results down to a crawl.

Here is an interesting way to look up columns that could possibly need indexed:
http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/spotting-missing-indexes-mariadb-mysql/2036/

Again, like the author said, "a query I use for MySQL / MariaDB to spot any columns that ***might*** need indexing" [emphasis mine]

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA, t.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, IFNULL(kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 'Not indexed') AS `Index` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES t 
    INNER JOIN information_schema.`COLUMNS` c 
    ON c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME 
    AND c.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Id' 
LEFT JOIN information_schema.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` kcu 
    ON kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME 
    AND kcu.COLUMN_NAME = c.COLUMN_NAME 
    AND kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION = 1    
 WHERE kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA IS NULL 
    AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql');
```

This code is very good :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Your answer would be a lot more useful if you could explain what your code does and how it works (and how to interpret the results). Just posting a wall of code doesn't help people learn. Thanks

Comment: This is copy/paste from the link http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/spotting-missing-indexes-mariadb-mysql/2036/ and it is described there

Comment: It just checks for columns ending with the name "id" that are unindexed... lol